# Cancan and console command "rake routes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, cancan

How can I get all routes (like command rake routes) in console for a specific user? I want only the routes that this user can access?

Does anyone know of a gem or is the best way to write my own console command handler?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you got any code you could share?

Comment: Actually I'm just interesting, is there any ready way(I have not found anything). If not - I will try do this my self, but I never tried to write rails console commands - I am new in rails.

Comment: You're interesting are you ;)

Comment: I'd go with the answer below. Before every ability you create, write a test for it. Fail the test, write the rule. Pass the test. You can't fail with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to write it by yourself (I don't know if there are cancan plugins for this).

First, cancan doesn't store what you can and cannot access in a specific place connected to routes, cancan only allows you to choose which method you can access for a given class or instance, like `can :read, User`, it's not tied in any way to the routes and at the same time routes are not tied directly to models (they are tied to controllers).

Based on this, it's also not that easy to write such a thing (not impossible, but not easy and I don't think is short).

Your best bet is try to emulate tests, you may try to access each route (you can probably parse the output of rake routes or read how that code is generated) with a given user and if the user can't access that path, you mark as non-accessible. You also need to give a way to select a user in your console command.